# Web inspector breakpoints set, but not breaking the code

Tags: ios, cordova, safari, web-inspector

I am trying to debug a Cordova app in the IOS simulator (IOS 8.1) on OSX Mavericks. I am using the Safari (7.0.6) web inspector. I can see the code, and the app is logging messages. When I set a breakpoint, the breakpoint tag shows in the code (dark grey) but the code does not stop at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've enabled breakpoints, they should be blue instead of gray:

[image]

The effect:

[image]